# Making Arrays in Jison

Tags: javascript, arrays, programming-languages, grammar, jison

I'm trying to add support for arrays in my programming language and am having trouble

```
Array
  : '[' Expr ("," Expr)* ']'
     {{ $$  = ['ArrayList', $1]; }}
  | '[' Expr ']'
     {{ $$ = ['Array', $2]; }}
  | '[' ']'
     {{ $$ = ['Empty']; }}
  ;
```

This however, will not parse "[1,2,3,4]." Jison tells me that it expects "]" but it got ",". Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not especially familiar with jison - do you need to change `","` to `','`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursion isn't interpreted or rejected. You have to split it into 2 elements to make it work:

```
Array
  : '[' Element ']'
     {{ $$  = ['ArrayList', $2]; }}
  ;

Element
  : Element "," Expr
     {{ $$ = $1 + ',' + $3 }}
  | Expr
     {{ $$ = $1 }};
```

This returns an Array as expected:

```
["ArrayList","1,2,3,4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`jison` does not accept EBNF. (It also doesn't reject it either, apparently.) So your rule:

```
Array
  : '[' Expr ("," Expr)* ']'
```

is interpreted as though it were:

```
Array
  : '[' Expr "," Expr ']'
```

You need to create an ExprList production:

```
Array   : '[' ExprList ']'
        | '[' ']'
        ;
ExprList: Expr
        | ExprList ',' Expr
        ;
```

Comment: Jison now supports EBNF syntax via the `%ebnf` declaration. See: https://gist.github.com/zaach/1659274